# Передача объекта с фрагмента в активити

Tags: java, android, классы, activity

Добрый день!

Имеется класс

```
class LoanParametr {

Integer typeOfPayment = 0, term = 0, weekend = 0, lastDayMonth = 0, firstInterestOnly = 0;
Double EDcom = 0.0, Ezhcom = 0.0, firstPayment = 0.0, summ = 0.0, percent = 0.0;
Long DateOfTheFirstPayment = 0L, DateOfIssue = 0L;
    String NameTable = "", NameCredit = "";


      LoanParametr(
            String NameTable,
            String NameCredit,
            Double summ,
            Long DateOfIssue,
            Long DateOfTheFirstPayment,
            Integer term,
            Double percent,
            Integer typeOfPayment,
            Double firstPayment,
            Integer firstInterestOnly,
            Integer weekend,
            Integer lastDayMonth,
            Double EDcom,
            Double Ezhcom
    ) {
        this.NameTable = NameTable;
        this.NameCredit = NameCredit;
        this.summ = summ;
        this.DateOfIssue = DateOfIssue;
        this.DateOfTheFirstPayment = DateOfTheFirstPayment;
        this.term = term;
        this.percent = percent;
        this.typeOfPayment = typeOfPayment;
        this.firstPayment = firstPayment;
        this.firstInterestOnly = firstInterestOnly;
        this.weekend = weekend;
        this.lastDayMonth = lastDayMonth;
        this.EDcom = EDcom;
        this.Ezhcom = Ezhcom;

    }
}
```

Хочу передать объект из фрагмента в активити посредством интерфейса, который объявлен внутри фрагмента

```
    public interface OnSelectParamsListener {
            void OnSelectParams(LoanParametr lp);


        }
```

Имлементируем в активити этот интерейфес

```
public class ActivityInputParams extends AppCompatActivity implements
        Params.OnSelectParamsListener,
        {
LoanParametr lp;    
    ...............
    @Override
        public void OnSelectParams(LoanParametr lp) {
            this.lp =lp;
```

Однако заметил, что если изначально lp равно null ссылка на экземпляр класса фрагмента спокойно переносится на объект этого класса созданный в активити, а если объявить пустой конструктор

```
 LoanParametr lp =  new LoanParametr();
```

То

```
this.lp = lp  не срабатывает.
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, чайнику как правильно переносить объекты из фрагмента в активити

Comment: В вопросе нет кода из фрагмента вызывающего метод. `((Params.OnSelectParamsListener)getActivity()).OnSelectParams(params);`
Такое ощущение, что у вас такого вызова нет, а вы ожидаете что оно должно само вызываться.

Comment: Я решил пропустить этот кусок кода так как уже пояснил, что у меня получается передавать объект, меня интересует почему я не могу присвоить (передать ссылку объекта) на другой объект, если тот не пустой. Для наглядного примера, будь это был бы какой-нибудь простой тип типа int, float то проблем с переносом данных не возникло

Comment: "почему я не могу присвоить (передать ссылку объекта) на другой объект" Можете. Из вашего вопроса и приведенного кода где у вас ошибка не видно.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.lp =lp;
```

замените на

```
ActivityInputParams.this.lp =lp;
```

А все потому, что `this` - ссылка на объект, которому принадлежит метод, в котором вы сейчас находитесь. Так вот, в этот момент вы находитесь не в `ActivityInputParams`, а в объекте анониммного класса, имплементирующего `OnSelectParamsListener`. И, естественно, у него поля `lp` нету.

Comment: Активити имплементит метод, поэтому `this` это как раз `ActivityInputParams.this`, иначе оно бы не скомпилилось просто.